# removing redundant ipython kernels

Tags: ipython, jupyter, conda, virtual-environment

I have currently 3 environments: root(base), aind-dl, py2env

So, for easy working, I've installed the conda extensions: nb_conda, nb_conda_kernels

and when I run `$: jupyter notebook` the nb_conda_kernel detects 5 kernels which are redundant and in the listing. Some kernels gives an error of not existing.

How do I remove the redundant kernels?

Envs i have:

[image: Envs]

redundant kernels:

[image: Redundant kernels]

Comment: Can you add the output of `jupyter kernelspec list`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/A2hMyIO these are env i have. and https://imgur.com/Fk2FxkN these are 2 redundant kernel detected by nb_conda_kernels Anaconda, conda root, and default belongs to same kernel.

Comment: Please do not post output from the terminal in images, and please edit your post to include the content.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you can use `jupyter kernelspec remove <env_name>` to remove a specific kernel.

In your case, your `conda root` and `default` seem to be leftovers from an Anaconda-Python 2 installation. The related discussion for this [issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1716) may be helpful. The idea is to disable/remove nb_conda. I have yet to run into this issue with Anaconda3 since I manage multiple kernels manually using the instructions [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments).

Comment: It works with `jupyter kernelspec remove <env_name>`.

Comment: @AntoniParellada What about base env? How to remove base kernel from list?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall redundant_kernel
```